# How to restart springboot application from code

Tags: spring-boot

I have a springboot application with embedded tomcat. And on certain cases it should be restarted from code.

I have read several articles and SO posts regarding this,but yet to find a clean solution.
I am aware that 'context.close' , 'SpringApplication.exit(context)' exist and can be wrapped into something like this:

```
public static void restart() {
    ApplicationArguments args = context.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        context.close();
        context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args.getSourceArgs());
    });
    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}
```

***source***: https://www.baeldung.com/java-restart-spring-boot-app

The problem is that using context.close() just doesn't work in a clean way.
 The context itself will be restarted though, but bunch of Threads will be left in the background (like  Thread[pool-3-thread-1,5,main]  Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]  Thread[OkHttp TaskRunner,5,main] ..etc). 
And for every context restart these will be recreated, so the number of threads adds up gradually by each restart. Resulting in huge Thread mess as time passes.

**Note1**: A simple application exit by using 'context.close()' also wouldn't work because of these left over Threads. So the context close doesnt even close the application.

**Note2**: If I use System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(context)) I can kill the app gracefully, but can't restart it.

**Note3**: I don't want to use neither devtools nor actuator

So the question is how to perform a total restart for a springboot application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **RestartEndPoint** in **spring-cloud-context** dependency to restart the Spring Boot application programmatically:

```
@Autowired
    private RestartEndpoint restartEndpoint;
    
    ...
    
    Thread restartThread = new Thread(() -> restartEndpoint.restart());
    restartThread.setDaemon(false);
    restartThread.start();
```